# UIView Animation not working with NSLayoutConstraint?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I have a keyboard notification and I want it so that when it goes off, the placeholder view animates to the left edge of the search bar.

Below is what I use to call the animation which is asynchronous with the keyboard opening. Currently, the view moves to the spot I want it to, however it's as if it's teleporting there rather than animating.

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if isKeyboardShowing {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.placeholder, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.searchBar, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 5).isActive = true
                }, completion: { (completed) in

                })

            }
        }
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animation with constraints could be a little bit tricky. First you need to adjust desired constraints, outside of the animation closure:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.placeholder, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.searchBar, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 5).isActive = true
```

Since constraint changes could cause other views change their position, you need ask superview (in the most cases the VC-view) to layout its subviews within the animation closure:

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }, completion: nil)
```

Therefore the superview adjusts subviews positions for you within the animation block.

Answer (score 1):

In order to animate a `NSLayoutConstraint`you need to put `setNeedsLayout()` in the animation block. You should then move the

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.placeholder, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.searchBar, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 5).isActive = true
```

to above the animation block like so:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.placeholder, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.searchBar, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 5).isActive = true
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: { (completed) in

})
```

Hope that helps!